# How can i remove a session in an array?

Tags: php

I need to write a product basket for my website, but I can't remove an index from array. I wrote an array index below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [urun_id] => 174
            [urun_adi] => ANT-5527N - Dual Polarity Parabolic Dish Anten 4.8-6.1Ghz 27Dbi
            [urun_fiyati] => 672
            [urun_fiyati_kur] => TL
            [urun_adeti] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [urun_id] => 149
            [urun_adi] => Cloud Router Switch 16x SFP+(10G ) 1Gbit Eth 
            [urun_fiyati] => 1683
            [urun_fiyati_kur] => TL
            [urun_adeti] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [urun_id] => 175
            [urun_adi] => ANT-5531N - Dual Polarity Parabolic Dish Anten 4.8-6.1Ghz 31Dbi
            [urun_fiyati] => 694
            [urun_fiyati_kur] => TL
            [urun_adeti] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) for this:

`unset($array[2]);` removes the element with index 2

Comment: BlobbyBob thans for your answer. I understand. How can i get array key with foreach? If i can get a array key. I can do that.

foreach($_SESSION["urun_listesi"] as $urun){

   echo ('<tr>
   <td>'. $urun["urun_adi"].'</td>
   <td>'. $urun["urun_adeti"].'</td>
   <td>'. $urun["urun_fiyati"].$urun["urun_fiyati_kur"] .'</td>
   <td><a href="sepet.php?sepettensil='.$urun["urun_id"].'">Ürün 
           Çıkart</a></td>
   </tr>
  
  ');

 echo ("<pre>");
 print_r($_SESSION["urun_listesi"]);
 echo ("</pre>");
 
  }

Comment: Output:

Array
(
    [174] => Array
        (
            [urun_id] => 174
            [urun_adi] => ANT-5527N - Dual Polarity Parabolic Dish Anten 4.8-6.1Ghz 27Dbi
            [urun_fiyati] => 672
            [urun_fiyati_kur] => TL
            [urun_adeti] => 1
        )

    [175] => Array
        (
            [urun_id] => 174
            [urun_adi] => ANT-5527N - Dual Polarity Parabolic Dish Anten 4.8-6.1Ghz 27Dbi
            [urun_fiyati] => 672
            [urun_fiyati_kur] => TL
            [urun_adeti] => 1
        )

Comment: [`foreach ($array as $key => $value)`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)